# Using sapply on date/factor vector field - include incrementing value

Tags: r, sapply

I have a date field (factor class converted to string) with missing values that I would like to fill with sequencing numbers for every missing value. Here is my code so far...

```
f<- function(x, counter){
  if(x == ""){
      counter = counter + 1; return (toString(counter))
  } else{
      return (toString(x))
  }
}
sapply(x$DateTime_, f, -9999)
```

The counter does not increment and returns a vector like:

```
[1] "-9998"    "-9998"    "-9998"    "-9998"    "-9998"    "1/1/1998"
```

Any help to get the counter to increment would be appreciated.

Comment: Read up on variable scope in R: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf. You're not incrementing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function passes -9999 to each call of f and then increments it by 1. This is why it's returning -9998 each time.

You probably want to maintain the counter variable in the parent environment and update it with the <<- operator. Something like this would do the trick for your example:

```
f = function(x) {
  if (x == "") {
    counter <<- counter + 1
    return(toString(counter))
  } else {
    return(toString(x))
  }
}
counter <- -9999
sapply(c("", "", "", "", "", "1/1/1998"), f)
```

Comment: You are a wizard. Can you point me to any resources that illustrate the differences between "<-" and "<<-".

Comment: Sure -- a reasonable introduction would be http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope. Thomas's comment above might be useful, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to accomplish the same goal. It takes advantage of logical indexing and the inherently vectorized comparison and replacement operators:

```
dates <- c("", "", "", "", "", "1/1/1998", "")
blanks <- dates == ""

dates[blanks] <- seq(from=-9999, by=1, length.out=sum(blanks))

dates
# [1] "-9999"    "-9998"    "-9997"    "-9996"    "-9995"    "1/1/1998" "-9994"
```