# R function runs, executes nothing (apparently)

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I'm trying to use a function to assign a single letter code to a data source variable based on one of 12 elements in a vector. This is the vector:

```
> Grps
 [1] "ST"  "RW"  "LW"  "CF"  "CM"  "CDM" "CAM" "RM"  "LM"  "CB"  "RB"  "LB"
```

This is the function: $PrimPos holds one of the values in Grps for each row, and $PosGrp is the destination for the single letter code ("F", "M", or "D".)

```
AsgnPos <- function(j, b, e, pos) 
       {for(q in b:e)
           {if(CompleteDataset$PrimPos[j] == Grps[q]) 
           { CompleteDataset$PosGrp[j] <- pos}
       }
}
```

And so then I loop through the data source (CompleteDataset), running three tests against the function to see which code to assign. (I realize I could break out of the routine once I got a hit, but for now it will iterate through all three tests). To the function, I pass:
 j...the row number of CompleteDataset//
 b...the first position of Grps for that category//
 e...the last position of Grps for that category//
 pos...the letter code to apply to $PosGrp//

```
for(i in 1:17981) {
 if(CompleteDataset$PrimPos[i] == "GK") {
   CompleteDataset$PosGrp[i] <- "G"
 } else {
    AsgnPos(i,1,4, "F")
    AsgnPos(i,5,9, "M")
    AsgnPos(i,10,12, "D")
 }  

}
```

I expect the for routine to be executed 17,981 times, once for each row of the data source. The first part works fine--it applies "G" to $PosGrp for any row that has "GK" in $PrimPos. I expect that in turn, the function will be run to check and see if $PrimPos for the current row matches one of the elements of the Grps vector. When it does, it should assign the letter code to $PosGrp.

The code executes without explicit errors, but other than assigning "G" to all matching rows, it does nothing. (I have the $PosGrp field defaulted to "Z", and other than the ones changed to "G" they are all still "Z".)

I've tried debugging but I'm brand new to that, and I can't seem to get it to step through the function even though I have it as a breakpoint, so I can't see what's happening in there. But am I missing something obvious in the logic?

Comment: You need to add a `return` argument in your function, so that it actually returns an output (so I guess the output would be `return(CompleteDataset)?) Second, I suggest you look at the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package. Third, as  rule of thumb don't assign things things outside and the function and then use them inside, e.g. add an argument `data` in your function and pass the dataset there. Similarly define `Grps` inside the function.

Comment: To echo @YannisVassiliadis, do you need to write your own function/is this for practice? You could use a combination of `case_when` or `if_else` from `dplyr` and `paste0` or `str_c` from `stringr`

Comment: I couldn't get case_when to work; no matter how many times I installed dplyr and loaded the library it wouldn't recognize the command. So I moved on. Also, I'm trying to teach myself so even if there's another way to go, this way should work as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example. Try the `<<-` for your assignment in your function. This reminds me of an old question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531514/using-sapply-on-date-factor-vector-field-include-incrementing-value

Comment: Yannis--how would a return argument work? I don't need it to return output; I want to assign a value to variable within the function. I'm not sure if I returned a value back to the function call, how it would assign to the var.

Sorry--also not clear what you're referring to about assigning things outside the function and then using them inside. Isn't that the whole point of function parameters, to bring values from outside to inside?

Comment: JMT--afraid I don't understand either piece of advice. I was told in an earlier question never to use << inside a function, but I couldn't ascertain why (other than it didn't seem to work anyway).

Comment: @MarkBunster I use it occasionally. It's fine. Edit your question with some sample data and people can help you better. Did you try `<<-` in your function you have shown above?

Comment: JMT--Well shoot! That did it. I suppose it makes some sense in retrospect; given that the assignment is to a variable outside the function. Thanks a lot! Make it an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an issue of scope. Try the `<<-` when operating on objects outside of your function.

```
AsgnPos <- function(j, b, e, pos) {
    for(q in b:e){
        if(CompleteDataset$PrimPos[j] == Grps[q]){
            CompleteDataset$PosGrp[j] <<- pos
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP wants to add a new variable `PosGrp` to `CompleteDataset` depending on the value of `PrimPos`. This can be efficiently done by joining with a *lookup* table.

#### Joining with a lookup table

First, the lookup table is constructed. It will include all groups including `"GK"`:

```
# as defined by OP
Grps <- c("ST", "RW", "LW", "CF", "CM", "CDM", "CAM", "RM", "LM", "CB", "RB", "LB")

library(data.table)
lookup <- data.table(
  PrimPos = c("GK", Grps), 
  PosGrp = c("G", rep("F", 4L), rep("M", 5L), rep("D", 3L))
)

lookup
```

> ```
>     PrimPos PosGrp
>  1:      GK      G
>  2:      ST      F
>  3:      RW      F
>  4:      LW      F
>  5:      CF      F
>  6:      CM      M
>  7:     CDM      M
>  8:     CAM      M
>  9:      RM      M
> 10:      LM      M
> 11:      CB      D
> 12:      RB      D
> 13:      LB      D
> ```

Note, that the column names are the same as used in `CompleteDataset`. This is not a requirement but saves some typing later on.

Now, we can join the lookup table with `CompleteDataset`. There are different options in R. The name `CompleteDataset` sounds as it might be a large data object. So, I suggest to use an *update while joining* which appends the new column *in place* to avoid taking a copy of the whole object.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(CompleteDataset)[lookup, on = "PrimPos", PosGrp := PosGrp]
```

With my dummy dataset (see *Data* section below), the modified

```
CompleteDataset
```

contains

> ```
>           rn PrimPos PosGrp
>     1:     1      LW      F
>     2:     2      CF      F
>     3:     3     CAM      M
>     4:     4      RB      D
>     5:     5      RW      F
>    ---                     
> 17977: 17977      LW      F
> 17978: 17978      RB      D
> 17979: 17979      RB      D
> 17980: 17980      CM      M
> 17981: 17981      RW      F
> ```

Alternatively, you can use base R

```
merge(CompleteDataset, lookup)
```

or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(CompleteDataset, lookup)
```

The result is the same but a new data object is created whre the order of rows and columns may have changed.

#### Reproducible dummy dataset

```
Grps <- c("ST", "RW", "LW", "CF", "CM", "CDM", "CAM", "RM", "LM", "CB", "RB", "LB")
n_rows <- 17981L
set.seed(1L)
CompleteDataset <- data.frame(
  rn = 1:n_rows,
  PrimPos = sample(c("GK", Grps), n_rows, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```